# How can git be fixed to allow rebases with unstaged changes that are not conflicting?

Tags: git, rebase

If you try to rebase with unstaged changes, git will show you:

```
error: cannot rebase: You have unstaged changes.
error: Please commit or stash them.
```

even when rebased contents are not conflicting at all with unstaged changes.

How one may skip `git stash` before rebase and `git stash pop` after rebase, and get this kind of error only on actual conflicts?

There is [`--autostash`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt---autostash) but in case of conflicts it will mangle code.

I want this error to appear only if `git stash` + rebase + `git stash pop` would result in conflicts.

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt---autostash?

Comment: @jonrsharpe "the final stash application after a successful rebase might result in non-trivial conflicts." vs "And get this kind of error only on actual conflicts?" - I am looking for solution that would check for conflicts before doing it rather than blindly mangle existing code.

Comment: I mentioned autostash for clarity.

Comment: Git doesn't know if there are going to be conflicts until it tries to apply the stash. That's how it finds out if there are actual conflicts - the error you're seeing isn't because there are "going to be conflicts", hence you see it when there won't be, it just checks whether the worktree is dirty.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I would be fine with "`stash` + rebase + `stash pop` + rewind if conflict appeared" process

Comment: @reducingactivity the process you describe is easily done manually, and it could also be scripted. Write a script `git-myrebase` that implements the logic you describe, and put it on your PATH. Then `git myrebase` will run it.

Comment: @joanis It seemed that either such script already exists (so there is no need to reinvent a wheel) or it is impossible to do for some reason.

Comment: @reducingactivity I agree with you it would be a nice thing for Git to support out of the box, but I guess the feature request didn't make it to the developers. It is certainly not impossible to implement, and I think it would not even be that difficult. Every Git command makes good use of exit codes, so it's a matter of checking the exit status at each step and proceeding accordingly. It has to be done with care, though, to avoid the risk of destroying uncommitted local changes, and that could be another reason no one has taken it on.

Comment: All that being said, my personal recommendation is to avoid rebasing in a dirty tree in the first place. I usually prefer to commit my work in progress rather than stash it, because it gives me much more control over the rebasing and conflict resolution processes, and much simpler rollback-ability.